# Detect finger leave of image button in android

Tags: android

I have an image button, i am trying to record an audio on touch of a button & when user leaves a button i stop recording.I am successfull in doing that.I have a problem when user starts moving its finger within that bounds of imagebutton.I am using on ACTION_MOVE to handle this, i am not getting 100% success , sometimes it detects on leave , sometimes not. Please help. Below is code i am using..

```
    @Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.btn_audio :

            final int action = event.getAction();

            // get the View's Rect relative to its parent
            v.getHitRect(rect);
            // offset the touch coordinates with the values from rect to obtain meaningful coordinates
            final float x = event.getX() + rect.left;
            final float y = event.getY() + rect.top;
            switch (action) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN :

                    audioBtn.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.img_audio_pressed));

                    mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(MSG_START_TIMER);
                    timer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    playBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE :

                    Log.e(TAG, rect.top+","+rect.bottom+","+rect.left+","+rect.right);
                    Log.e(TAG, (int)x+","+(int)y);

                    if (!rect.contains((int) x, (int) y)) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "In action move,outside");
                        audioBtn.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.img_audio));
                        playBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        if (stop)
                            mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(MSG_STOP_TIMER);
                    } else {

                        Log.e(TAG, "In action move,inside");
                        audioBtn.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.img_audio_pressed));

                        timer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        playBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP :
                    // the user raised his finger, cancel the Runnable
                    audioBtn.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.img_audio));
                    playBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    if (stop)
                        mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(MSG_STOP_TIMER);
                    break;
            }

            break;

        default :

            break;
    }

    return false;
}
```

XML ::

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/actvity_background"
android:padding="15dp" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/record_review"
        style="@style/textview.review"
        android:layout_below="@id/rating_app"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="Record a review" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/record"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/record_review"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:splitMotionEvents="false"
        android:weightSum="2" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/audio_record"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btn_audio"
                style="@style/imagebutton"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:contentDescription="@string/desc_provider_thumb"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                android:src="@drawable/img_audio" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/timer"
                style="@style/textview.review"
                android:layout_below="@id/btn_audio"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:text="00:30"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btn_play"
                style="@style/imagebutton"
                android:layout_below="@id/btn_audio"
                android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/timer"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:contentDescription="@string/desc_provider_thumb"
                android:src="@drawable/img_play"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btn_pause"
                style="@style/imagebutton"
                android:layout_below="@id/btn_audio"
                android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/timer"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:contentDescription="@string/desc_provider_thumb"
                android:src="@drawable/img_pause"
                android:visibility="gone" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/video_record"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btn_video"
                style="@style/imagebutton"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:contentDescription="@string/desc_provider_thumb"
                android:src="@drawable/img_video" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/video_preview"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:visibility="gone" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/img_dumy_home_video_thumbnail" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/play_button"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/img_play" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_rerecord"
                style="@style/button.review"
                android:layout_below="@id/video_preview"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                android:text="@string/re_record"
                android:visibility="gone" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_submit_review"
        style="@style/button.review"
        android:layout_below="@id/record"
        android:text="Submit review" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: what do you mean by _"sometimes it detects on leave"_ based on your code above? Which part of code is executed?

Comment: @AmulyaKhare When i tap the imagebutton(Action_Down) & leave(Action_up) it works fine.But in case of action_move.. sometimes it detects on leave & sometimes not...

Comment: what is _"on leave"_?

Comment: @AmulyaKhare leaves the periferi(bounds) of button..

Comment: so it executes the `if`.. `Log.e(TAG, "In action move,outside");`?

Comment: it should execute if (!rect.contains((int) x, (int) y)) {Log.e(TAG,"Inaction move,outside");....} this part of code when an user leaves the button ,, but it is not doing so..

Answer (score 0):

```
return true
```

instead of

```
return false
```

in your onTouch method

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `v.getHitRect(rect);` use `getLocationInWindow()` which returns screen co-ordinates instead of co-ordinates relative to the parent. Update your `onTouch` code as follows:

```
//same here
...
...    
int[] location = new int[2];
v.getLocationInWindow(location); // get position on the screen.

rect  = new Rect(location[0], location[1], location[0]+v.getWidth(), location[1]+v.getHeight());

final float x = event.getX(); // screen x position
final float y = event.getY(); // screen y position
...
...
//same here
```

Comment: these dosent help... even if i tap on image button it says it has detected outside of button...

Comment: @AnkitOstwal actually the code works perfectly for me. I think it may be because of some layout issue. Can you post your XML? Also do you have any other `onTouchListeners`? They may be conflicting with this one?

Comment: Another possibility is that you are changing the `playBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);` which may change the `view` positions and lead to such behaviour.. comment that and test again..

Comment: Pls check out the xml...& Please provide your view on it... you will find an imagebutton with id "btn_audio".. On touch of it i am performing the java code which is written above.